# Silverlight duplex with WF

Tags: silverlight-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

I have read the below article and it would seem that it's not possible to use duplex communications to a WF from a silverlight client.

Is this really the case? Are there not a work arounds to this? If not, I find this a strange omission.

http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2010/05/03/workflow-4-services-and-duplex-communications.aspx

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason Silverlight doesn't cut it as a client for WF4 duplex communication is the long running nature of workflows. WF4 reasons, correctly, that a client will not be around for the entire duration of the workflow so the normal duplex channel, which relies on the client keeping the proxy object alive, is not good enough. So WF4 uses durable duplex where the duplex callback is really a completely separate call and doesn't rely on the original proxy object. But the result is that it requires the client to be a WCF ServiceHost and therefore full WCF stack. And of course Silverlight only contains the client part of the WCF stack and not the ServiceHost as that is normally not needed in the browser.

As far a workarounds go. If you know your workflow isn't around for a long time you can use the Silverlight polling duplex to communicate with a standard WCF service and have that communicate with the duplex workflow.

But that said, it makes the architecture quite a bit more complex and duplex WCF is already a complex and error prone beast so I would only do this when really needed.